# ESP32 - ESPAsyncWebServer - server.client()?

Tags: javascript, server, arduino, esp32

I am working on the ESP32 at the moment, and I need to integrate a new part in my already made program, the problem is that in my program I use a: AsyncWebServer, and this new part (camera ) works with: ESP32WebServer, so I try to integrate the camera is to make it work with my already programmed server, but I am stuck on this line:

```
#include <ESP32WebServer.h> <---- #include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
```

ESP32WebServer server (80); <----- AsyncWebServer server (80);

WiFiClient client = server.client (); <----- ???

I can't find the equivalent of: server.client () when I use: AsyncWebServer.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ESPAsyncWebServer` doesn't use `WiFiClient` objects.

`WiFiClient` is a poorly named interface to a raw TCP connection. `ESPAsyncWebServer` doesn't use `WiFiClient`, it uses [`AsyncTCP`](https://github.com/me-no-dev/AsyncTCP) instead, which is where its asynchrony derives from (plus a lot of work in the web server itself).

It has a `client()` method, but that method returns an `AsyncClient` object. That's the closest you're going to get to getting a `WiFiClient`. Don't expect it to work exactly the same way or have exactly the same methods.

If you want to use the camera software with the async web server, you'll need to rewrite the camera software to work with it, or run a second web server on a different port number.

Comment: thank you, i added a second server and it work fine now

Comment: If it's working, please accept this answer as a solution so that other people can that it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this [Github example](https://github.com/GreenPonik/esp32-asyncTCP-server-example/tree/master/src) shown, we can not get client directly.
So my solution is listen to new client event and add pointer of AsyncClient to array.
We can remove from array or list afterward by listen to client disconnect event.
This is code from the link.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define SSID "esp-tcp-server"
#define PASSWORD "123456789"

#define SERVER_HOST_NAME "esp-tcp-server"

#define TCP_SERVER_PORT 8000
#define DNS_PORT 53

#endif // CONFIG_H

static DNSServer DNS;

static void handleData(void *arg, AsyncClient *client, void *data, size_t len)
{
  Serial.printf("\n data received from client %s \n", client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
  Serial.write((uint8_t *)data, len);

  //our big json string test
  String jsonString = "{\"data_from_module_type\":5,\"hub_unique_id\":\"hub-bfd\",\"slave_unique_id\":\"\",\"water_sensor\":{\"unique_id\":\"water-sensor-ba9\",\"firmware\":\"0.0.1\",\"hub_unique_id\":\"hub-bfd\",\"ip_address\":\"192.168.4.2\",\"mdns\":\"water-sensor-ba9.local\",\"pair_status\":127,\"ec\":{\"value\":0,\"calib_launch\":0,\"sensor_k_origin\":1,\"sensor_k_calibration\":1,\"calibration_solution\":1,\"regulation_state\":1,\"max_pumps_durations\":5000,\"set_point\":200},\"ph\":{\"value\":0,\"calib_launch\":0,\"regulation_state\":1,\"max_pumps_durations\":5000,\"set_point\":700},\"water\":{\"temperature\":0,\"pump_enable\":false}}}";
  // reply to client
  if (client->space() > strlen(jsonString.c_str()) && client->canSend())
  {
    client->add(jsonString.c_str(), strlen(jsonString.c_str()));
    client->send();
  }
}

static void handleError(void *arg, AsyncClient *client, int8_t error)
{
  Serial.printf("\n connection error %s from client %s \n", client->errorToString(error), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
}

static void handleDisconnect(void *arg, AsyncClient *client)
{
  Serial.printf("\n client %s disconnected \n", client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
}

static void handleTimeOut(void *arg, AsyncClient *client, uint32_t time)
{
  Serial.printf("\n client ACK timeout ip: %s \n", client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
}

static void handleNewClient(void *arg, AsyncClient *client)
{
  Serial.printf("\n new client has been connected to server, ip: %s", client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
  // register events
  client->onData(&handleData, NULL);
  client->onError(&handleError, NULL);
  client->onDisconnect(&handleDisconnect, NULL);
  client->onTimeout(&handleTimeOut, NULL);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // create access point
  while (!WiFi.softAP(SSID, PASSWORD, 6, false, 15))
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // start dns server
  if (!DNS.start(DNS_PORT, SERVER_HOST_NAME, WiFi.softAPIP()))
    Serial.printf("\n failed to start dns service \n");

  AsyncServer *server = new AsyncServer(TCP_SERVER_PORT); // start listening on tcp port 7050
  server->onClient(&handleNewClient, server);
  server->begin();
}

void loop()
{
  DNS.processNextRequest();
}
```